# In the SpriteKit framework, how can I make a sprite point in the direction a sprites PhysicsBody is going?

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a sprite moving around the scene, that has physics. I want to create a motion blur effect, but I am stuck on getting it so that the SKSPriteNode with the blurred image is pointing in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The SKPhysicsBody has a velocity and angularVelocity property. Those properties can be used to determine your direction for this purpose.

You can use the `zRotation` property of any SKNode to adjust it's rotation to get the proper facing.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
-(void)didSimulatePhysics {
    if (node.physicsBody.velocity.dx!=0 || node.physicsBody.velocity.dy!=0)
        node.zRotation = atan2(node.physicsBody.velocity.dy, node.physicsBody.velocity.dx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an SKAction there is a parameter called OrientToPath.  This will align your object with the path it is on.  All you have to do initially is ensure the orientation starts in the right position.

SKAction.followPath(cgpath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, duration: 5)